# Make paragraph auto fill remaining height of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my current project I have the following structure

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <section>
            <h1>some title</h1>
            <p>some text</p>
        </section>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

The `ol` has a variable but set height which is filled by the `li` (via `height:100%;`). Now I want the text in the paragraph to fill the remaining height (via `line-height` and/or `font-size`).

I have researched this but didn't really find a solution to this, only FitText.js but it "is for gigantic display text only" as they say.

So I've come up with a JavaScript solution, calculating the remaining height from two perspectives (default `line-height: 1em` and `line-height: 0em`) and calculate the required `line-height` so remaining height is 0 (via basic maths, interpolating the function `y = a*x + b` where `y` equals the remaining height).

```
var outerHeight = $("section").innerHeight(),
    h1Height = $("section").children("h1").first().outerHeight(),
    pHeight = $("section").children("p").first().outerHeight();

var defaultHeight, a, b, x;

defaultHeight = outerHeight - (h1Height + pHeight);
$("section").children("p").first().css("line-height", "0em");
b = outerHeight - (h1Height + $("section").children("p").first().outerHeight());
a = defaultHeight - b;
x = -b / a;
$("section").children("p").first().css("line-height", x+"em");
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hpM2/)

Finally **my question**: Is it possible to achieve this in a better way (pure CSS would be awesome but I doubt that)? If not, what events could occur in which I had to recalculate (resizing browser eg)?

Also I'd like the text to fill the section to maximum extent - currently the last line's `line-height` might create a small visible area between the characters and the bottom of the section.

Comment: Why not set the height to `auto`?

Comment: @Blaine That of the section? The `ol` is vertical and has 3 elements as shown - I want all of them to have the same height, so I didn't think of it. Will research this however, so thanks already ;)

Comment: Or you can wrap that section in a div and set that to `auto`, then the children elements would fill the parent automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looked interesting to me, so I thought I might take a crack at it. Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7hpM2/1/) that might give you some new ideas.

1. I switched everything to divs (not sure why, perhaps it's just me)
2. I made the assumption that the title would be fixed in size, and the text would be distributed over the size of the large div minus the size of the title.
3. Then a simple division of totalheight and initial size of the text.

Obviously it won't work at the extremes (three words, or a book-length text.

I left the alerts in just for show, obviously you can delete them or comment them out.

JS

```
var outerheight = $(".oldiv").innerHeight();
var titleheight = $(".oldiv div:first-child").outerHeight();
var textheight = $(".oldiv div:last-child").outerHeight();
var heighttodistribute = outerheight - titleheight;

alert( outerheight + '-' + titleheight + '-' + textheight + '-' + heighttodistribute);

var newlineheight = heighttodistribute / textheight;

alert(newlineheight);


$('.oldiv div:last-child').css('line-height', newlineheight);
```

Comment: Looks &/ works good, thanks! Do you have an idea if it is possible (and if so, how) that the last line of the paragraph "touches" the end of `.olddiv` - currently there is still some space (probably due to the `line-height` on the last line)?

Comment: I wonder if "rounding" the number might make a difference. I'll play a bit.

Comment: I've tried .round, .floor and .ceil, and the best from my perspective is to just leave the division alone.